# How do you securely expose a service from AX to the web?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I'm writing a service in AX that you can call and query customer data if you authenticate somehow.  What's the most common and generally considered safe method of exposing this externally?

How does one authenticate?  Should I wrap the AX web service in C#?

Comment: Authentification is through windows integrated security as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AX allows to expose a WCF web service in the internet through IIS, in the IIS Manager you can configure some rules that provides security in the web site that holds your service such a authorization and autentiacation rules, permisions, etc. See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772206(v=ws.10).aspx) article.

In the enhanced inbound port you can also configure the WCF Service security in the binding configuration go to **TrasportSecurity Properties**, **MessageSecurity Properties** etc.

In the port you can set another security cusmomization if you want deny user access for example. See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202131.aspx)

You can see the documentation for the WCF security here msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925(v=vs.110).aspx.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

AOS should not be directly exposed to external internet (behind firewall). So you should use service bus. This whitepaper describes mobile development but it similar to your problem. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukax/archive/2013/08/29/developing-secure-mobile-apps-for-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012.aspx